# Marshalling DIDL-Lite with Go's xml package

Tags: xml, go

Here's a sample [DIDL-Lite](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22didl-lite%22) XML document from the [UPnP AV ContentDirectory v2 Service Template](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-ContentDirectory-v2-Service.pdf&ei=e9LFT-LyDqasiAf-uKD-Ag&usg=AFQjCNFhcBJ9BMlvj0uT1osj_W5rZpo3Fw&sig2=9BCKwUcpkPvXyJ44pvfXtA):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DIDL-Lite
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"
 xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/didl-lite-v2-20060531.xsd
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/upnp-v2-20061231.xsd">
   <item id="18" parentID="13" restricted="0">
      ...
   </item>
</DIDL-Lite>
```

How would one go about marshalling **to** this with [Go's xml package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/)? More specifically:

1. How are namespace prefixes defined, such as `xmlns:dc` and `xmlns:upnp`?
2. How are multiple name spaces configured on an element?
3. How is the namespace set for attributes, such as the `xsi` prefix on the `schemaLocation` attribute?

As a base, I have something like this:

```
type DIDLLite struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/ DIDL-Lite"`
    // ??? namespace prefixes dc, upnp, xsi
    Objects []Object
}
```

I've also found [this](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3526) possibly related bug.

Comment: Dear downvoter: FWIW, I hate XML, and there's no clear way to do this with the existing XML packages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you gave *is* marshalled.  I assume you mean to ask, "how would one define Go data types that marshal with xml.Marshal into this?"

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type DIDLLite struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    DC      string   `xml:"xmlns:dc,attr"`
    UPNP    string   `xml:"xmlns:upnp,attr"`
    XSI     string   `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
    XLOC    string   `xml:"xsi:schemaLocation,attr"`
    Objects []Object `xml:"item"`
}

type Object struct {
    ID         string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Parent     string `xml:"parentID,attr"`
    Restricted string `xml:"restricted,attr"`
}

func main() {
    d := DIDLLite{
        XMLName: xml.Name{
            Space: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/",
            Local: "DIDL-Lite",
        },
        DC:   "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
        UPNP: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/",
        XSI:  "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        XLOC: `
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/didl-lite-v2-20060531.xsd
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/upnp-v2-20061231.xsd`,
        Objects: []Object{{ID: "18", Parent: "13", Restricted: "0"}},
    }
    b, err := xml.MarshalIndent(d, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Output:

```
<DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/didl-lite-v2-20060531.xsd
   urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/
    http://www.upnp.org/schemas/av/upnp-v2-20061231.xsd">
    <item id="18" parentID="13" restricted="0"></item>
</DIDL-Lite>
```

which can be pretty printed to match your example above.  xml.MarshallIndent is a little primitive yet.

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to bake in default namespace URIs similar to the one that can be specified for `xml.Name`? Also fantastic answer, thanks for digging through this awful stuff.