# Consuming SOAP with namespaces in GOLANG

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, go

i'm a GO newbie, starting to learn how to process SOAP requests. I have a difficulty here with the namespaces: i don't know how to contruct the structs to reflect such kind of data coming in from the webservice in order to unmarshall it. Could you give me a few hints here? I'm using GO 1.5.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:doQueryAllSysStatusResponse>
        <ns1:sysCountryStatus>

            <ns1:item>
                <ns1:countryId>1</ns1:countryId>
                <ns1:programVersion>1.0</ns1:programVersion>
                <ns1:catsVersion>1.1.87</ns1:catsVersion>
                <ns1:apiVersion>1.0</ns1:apiVersion>
                <ns1:attribVersion>1.0</ns1:attribVersion>
                <ns1:formSellVersion>1.4.46</ns1:formSellVersion>
                <ns1:siteVersion>1.0</ns1:siteVersion>
                <ns1:verKey>123131231</ns1:verKey>
            </ns1:item>

            <ns1:item>
                <ns1:countryId>56</ns1:countryId>
                <ns1:programVersion>1.0</ns1:programVersion>   
                <ns1:catsVersion>1.0.43</ns1:catsVersion>
                <ns1:apiVersion>1.0</ns1:apiVersion> 
                <ns1:attribVersion>1.0</ns1:attribVersion>
                <ns1:formSellVersion>1.0.69</ns1:formSellVersion>
                <ns1:siteVersion>1.0</ns1:siteVersion>
                <ns1:verKey>00000101</ns1:verKey>
            </ns1:item>
        </ns1:sysCountryStatus>
    </ns1:doQueryAllSysStatusResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: The `encoding/xml` standard package supports namespaces natively -- the encoding and decoding rules are explained [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) and [there](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) in the doc, respectively. The reference manual is a bit dry, so did you try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[go]+xml+namespace)? In particular, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10812294/720999) might be quite illustrative of the approach.

Comment: Hi kostix and thank you for great piece of advice. I think that the link you provided (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10812294/720999) answers all my dilemas, it seems like i missed the functionality of "attr"

Answer (score 1):

You can a structure that matches your SOAP data and then unmarshal it with the "encoding/xml" package

Structs :

```
type Envelope struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Envelope"`
    Body     Body     `xml:"SOAP-ENV:Body"`
}

type Body struct {
    StatusRes *DoQueryAllSysStatusResponse `xml:"ns1:doQueryAllSysStatusResponse"`
}

type DoQueryAllSysStatusResponse struct {
    CountryStatus *SysCountryStatus `xml:"ns1:sysCountryStatus"`
}

// ...
```

Unmarshal:

```
data := []byte{} // SOAP data
env := &Envelope{}
err := xml.Unmarshal(data, env)
if err != nil {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hi basgys, this is the approach i tried at first but it produced the following message:

expected element type <SOAP-ENV:Envelope> but have <Envelope>

that's why i started diggind further, thanks anyway!